# Spotipy- Why is there a 50 song limit when getting saved songs?

Tags: python, api, spotify, spotipy

I am using the Python Spotify library Spotipy with a Raspberry Pi, and I am wondering why there is a 50 song limit when trying to see the user's saved songs? I have looked at the documentation, but I am still confused on the reason. If you answer this thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They don't expect users to be regularly retrieving *all* of a user's songs, only a portion of them (and potentially by filtered query). In addition, it could be a waste of data if 100 songs are sent, but the user only ends up using one song.

Fifty is a sensible limit, and there is pagination to allow for accessing more than fifty songs in a series of smaller requests (rather than one large request).

Comment: That does make sense, I will look up how to do that. Thank you

Comment: @ChristianMoore Did this answer your question?